# Preserve anchor names when dumping class with ruamel.yaml and filtering through __getstate__ and __setstate__

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml, getstate

I have classes that are setup to be loaded/dumped using ruamel.yaml 0.17.21 `yaml_object` decorator.

For some reason, I don't want changes in my class to be saved to yaml, unless specifically requested by the user. To do that, I use the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods to cache the initial_state and the user is directed to modify this object if they want a permanent change.

Everything works as excepted, except that the name of the anchors are lost when dumping.
I was not able to pinpoint how ruamel.yaml preserves those normally when the `__{set|get}state__` methods are not defined.

Those easy-to-read anchor names are very important to me as a user-friendly feature.

Here's an example:

```
import sys
from copy import deepcopy
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)
class ExampleClass():

    def __init__(self):
        self._permanent_state = {}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(deepcopy(state))
        self._permanent_state = state

    def __getstate__(self):
        return self._permanent_state
        

source = """
simple: &simple !ExampleClass
    potato: 10
    turnip: 20

nested: !ExampleClass
    sunflower: 30
    others: *simple
"""
a = yaml.load(source)
a['simple'].potato = 10**6 # Should not be reflected in dump
a['nested']._permanent_state['sunflower'] = 100 # Should be reflected in dump
yaml.dump(a, sys.stdout)
```

Output has `simple` anchor renamed to `id001`:

```
simple: &id001 !ExampleClass
  potato: 10
  turnip: 20
nested: !ExampleClass
  sunflower: 100
  others: *id001
```

If I remove the `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods

```
import sys
from copy import deepcopy
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, yaml_object

yaml = YAML()

@yaml_object(yaml)
class ExampleClass():
    pass

source = """
simple: &simple !ExampleClass
    potato: 10
    turnip: 20

nested: !ExampleClass
    sunflower: 30
    others: *simple
"""
a = yaml.load(source)
a['simple'].potato = 10**6   # Should not be reflected in dump
a['nested']._permanent_state = deepcopy(a['nested'].__dict__)
a['nested']._permanent_state['sunflower'] = 100  # Should not be reflected in dump
yaml.dump(a, sys.stdout)
```

Output now preserves the `simple` anchor (but the desired behaviour is lost):

```
simple: &simple !ExampleClass
  potato: 1000000
  turnip: 20
nested: !ExampleClass
  sunflower: 30
  others: *simple
  _permanent_state:
    sunflower: 100
    others: !ExampleClass
      potato: 1000000
      turnip: 20
```

Ideally I would like the behaviour of the first example, while preserving the anchor name.

Answer (score 1):

Had you not provided a counterexample, I would have guessed the anchor would not be preserved on a instance of any registered class.

The presence of `__setstate__` forces a different execution path in the constructor in which the anchor information is not actively dropped, but just not used. It is probably possible to subclass (and use) the `RoundTripConstructor` and `RoundTripRepresenter` to store/retrieve the anchor information available in the node.
In the same way you will lose comments that are "part of" your tagged mapping.

It is probably easiest to load the YAML document without registering `ExampleClass` and then recursively walking over the loaded data, looking for "dict" (subclass) instances that have the `.tag` attribute (actually a property) set to `!ExcampleClass` and replace those with an appropriately behaving instance ( or possible adding the specific behaviour you want, using duck-typing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll have to look into the constructor to see what's up. This single tweak would go a long way for me.

I presume that `RoundTripConstructor` should be my starting point? If not, where should I start?

Comment: `RoundTripConsttructor:construct_yaml_object` put some print statement in so that you are sure you hit it. That method  is a generator that is used is a two step process, which is necessary to be able to build (indirect) self-referential structures as is allowed in YAML.